# Error with Json.NET in Portable Class Library

Tags: serialization, json.net, portable-class-library

I created a Portable Class Library that targets .Net 4.5, Silverlight 4 and higher, Windows Phone 7 and higher and Windows Store.

Then I downloaded Json.NET from http://json.codeplex.com, referenced the Newtonsoft.Json.dll from the Bin\Portable folder, add "using Newtonsoft.Json;" to my class, but when I compile it, I got the error:

The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But I've already referenced it. Did I use the wrong version?

I also tried using Nuget to get Json.NET directly from my PCL project, but the one got added to my project only contains a very small set of functionalities (no async versions and no SerializeXNode on JsonConvert object).

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Portable Class Library is targeting Windows Phone 7.5 and not just Windows Phone 7.0.  However, it may be that the PCL version of Json.NET which supports WP7.5 doesn't have the features you are looking for.  WP7.5 doesn't have async support without the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package, for example, and I don't know if Json.NET took advantage of that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried making the PCL target WP7.5 instead of WP7, but I got the exact same error. It looks like I didn't reference that DLL at all. I also added all the BCL libraries to my PCL, but same result

Answer (score 0):

Already add from Nuget Microsoft.Bcl.Async ?